# Can't compile Super Mario 64 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: gcc, makefile, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having trouble compiling this [github repo for Super Mario 64](https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64). I followed all of the steps.

- I made sure I had all of the dependencies like build essential installed
- I cloned the repo and copied a rom for asset extraction
- I used the Makfile by running `make VERSION=us -j4`

The compiler did it's thing and gave a few warnings which is to be expected, but it didn't give any errors and make said the sha1 checksums matched. When I went into the build directory and tried executing sm64.us.bin, it gave this error: `bash: ./sm64.us.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. When I googled the error, I found that some people got it when trying to run a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit OS, but that can't be it because I'm running a 64 bit kernel on a 64 bit machine and compiling it myself. I checked the permission bits and there don't seem to be any issues there. I even tried deleting the repo and cloning it again which didn't work. I then tried running different flags like -j5 or without the -j flag entirely (That shouldn't make a difference since I'm running a fairly zippy 12 core Ryzen 5 but I thought I'd try having GCC compile on a single core because I was running out of ideas). What am I doing wrong here? Is there a setting with GCC I should change or could there be a problem with the makefile?

---

**UPDATE:**

I checked the ELF file and it looks like it is 32 bit for some reason. I ran `file sm64.us.elf` and the output was `sm64.us.elf: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-III version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`. Why is GCC doing that? How can I compile a 64 bit executable?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be able to run the resulting files this way. The problem is not with 32 bits, but with the architecture (MIPS, which is not what desktop PCs use). Maybe you're supposed to run it using an emulator?

Comment: That's a good point. I did try running sm64.us.bin with an N64 emulator called mupen64plus and got a blank screen with no error output in the terminal. I tried running the rom I used for asset extraction to make sure that the emulator wasn't the problem and it ran just fine. I think you're right that the makefile probably wasn't designed to compile to x86.

Comment: I marked this as solved since it's clear that the makefile wasn't meant to compile an x86 version. I know it's possible since people have released native x86 binaries for Mario 64 but it seems that this is a far more advanced skill than I thought. Just on the comment of running 32 bit executables, I wrote the test code in C and compiled with the -m32 flag and it ran just fine. ```if (sizeof(size_t) < 8) printf("I'm a 32 bit binary\n"); else printf("I'm a 64 bit binary\n");``` I will try to get it running in an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC can build 32bit or 64bit executables (on most systems). It all depends on what arguments you give it. If you look at the compile invocation that make is running you'll likely see that it passes the `-m32` (or some similar) option, which tells the compiler and linker to create 32bit objects and binaries.

If you want to build 64bit instead you'll have to find the arguments in your makefile or other configuration that select 32bit, and remove them (or change them to explicitly choose 64bit).

I should warn you, *this almost certainly won't work!!*  It's not the case that any old C program can be compiled as either 32bit or 64bit and continue to work identically.  It is *possible*, but doing this requires that the programmer write their code carefully and with forethought.  In my experience video game programs are almost always coded specifically for a given hardware target and little thought is given to making it portable to other hardware, and that includes 64bit versions of the "same" vendor.

Instead of trying to make the code build for 64bit, a better use of your time is to investigate why your system is not able to run a 32bit executable and fix that.  It's odd to me that you can compile for 32bit but not run 32bit: usually if you can build it then you have the proper libraries, etc. installed to run.

Comment: Those are MIPS binaries, and OP is running the regular x86_64. Probably the makefile doesn't make native binaries, but cross-compiles ROMs that can be used in an emulator.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see the edited update that showed the output of `file`.  Right.  You'll definitely need an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

put an sm64 rom (US) in the folder. if its HackerSM64, name it **baserom.us.z64**. and if its normal decomp. name it **baserom.us**

edit: itll be in [hack folder]\build\sm64.z64